Is it necessary to set `secure: true` when connecting to an https server?
I have a Nodejs backend that my frontend proxies to through Nginx, which is responsible for routing all traffic. I'm using Let's Encrypt, and the server can be accessed by going to it (https://example.com). I also have load balancing setup to route traffic upstream via the 'least connections' protocol.
On the frontend, I connect socket.io like this:
import { io, ManagerOptions, SocketOptions } from 'socket.io-client';

const otherOpts = {};
const socket = io('https://example.com', {
    ...otherOpts,
    secure: false,
} as Partial<ManagerOptions & SocketOptions>);

This works as is, but in the current context, what would I need secure: true for? Is this the condition that determines ws vs wss? The client connects over https already, so is this something I can safely omit?

Take a look at the the documentation. There is no option secure for the client side. This option is only used on the server-side.

I guess they're using the underlying types from engineio-client, because Typescript is telling me that secure is, indeed, an option

The documentation on that type also says If this is a secure connection. Set from the URI passed when connecting. It appears to be meant as a read-only flag, not an option you're supposed to set.

Hence my confusion, thank you all very much, closing
